# Dual Boot: Can't boot Arch Linux

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

**my History**

I got a PC with Intel 64 Bit Processor. 
There I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS at `/dev/sdb1` and Arch Linux at `/dev/sda1`.

Both swap onto `/dev/sdb2`.

I tried (with succes) to install Arch Linux onto a SD-Card (`/dev/sdc`) for my raspberry pi. There I tried to install vim to the SD-Card using `pacstrap`. This produced a few errors. Then I plugged off my SD-Card reader.

After rebooting my PC I saw a `GRUB_RESCUE>` promt. And the Line:

```
error:no such device:5a28b060-333c-479a-b5ed-58a7b9d8ae77.
```

This is the UUID of my Ubuntu partition (`/dev/sdb1`)

**my first try**

Then I used my *amd64 boot repair disc* and installed GRUB onto `/dev/sdb`. Then I had to disable `/dev/sda` in the Bios and Ubuntu is booting nicely.

Arch was'nt shown up at this moment.

Then I ran `sudo update-grub` and rebooted. Then Arch Linux was shown up but if I selected

*Arch on /dev/sda1* my satadisc or somthing like that produced a ugly sound and my PC rebooted.

The output was

```
:~$ sudo update-grub
Grub-Konfigurationsdatei wird generiert …              #generating grub.cfg
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-35-generic     #Linux-image found
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-35-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-34-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-34-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-33-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-33-generic
Linux-Abbild gefunden: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-32-generic
initrd-Abbild gefunden: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-32-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Arch auf /dev/sda1 gefunden             #found Arch on /dev/sda1
erledigt                          #done
```

interesting is that GRUB says only 'found Arch on /dev/sda1'.

**my second try**

Then I tried to install GRUB onto `/dev/sda` and activated `sda` in the Bios.
Then my machine produced again this ugly sound and I had to start again with the *boot repair disc*

**my fourth try**

is this here. I checked the `/boot` folder of Arch and of Ubuntu the differents are:

-Arch has got two `initramfs.img` (one is fallback) images

-Ubuntu has got a few `initrd.img` images(different versions)

-Ubuntu has got a few `System.map` files(see above)

-Ubuntu has got a few config files(again for the different versions)

-Ubuntu has got a few 'abi' files(what's that?)

And the filesystem of my Arch-partition is not damaged.

By the way I don't want to reinstall Arch because my installation is at a point where it would be really a *lot* work to rebuild the system.

Could it be that my MBR of `/dev/sda` are damaged?

Now I want to be able again to start both Operating Systems properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `/boot/grub.cfg` is defined wich partition is used as root partition for the (unix-like)OSs.

Here in my case Arch is not booting, if his root partition is called by the name `/dev/sdXY`. I changed this using `vim` (`vi` should do it as well)
using the command

```
:%s/\/dev\/sdXY/UUID=my-uuid/g
```

this substitutes every `/dev/sdXY` with `my-uuid`

Comment: It's indeed always advised to use UUID or labels over the traditional way (/dev/sdX) because it's the only way to guaranty the persistence of partition names.

Comment: Yap, the `grub-mkconfig` uses only for better readability the `/dev/sdXY` form, better would be the UUID form, in the `fstab`,too.